# Change column name by mapping with another dataDrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have imported csv file with 14 columns & I want to rename all the column name which is present in one dataframe "columnNameDF"

Source Data:

```
Column1,Column2,Column3,Column4,Column5,Column6,Column7,Column8,Column9,Column10,Column11,Column12,Column13,Column14
1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14
```

Column Rename Stored in columnNameDF.

```
SourceColumns   Rename
Column1     Snapshot Date
Column2     Quarter End
Column3     Year End
Column4     RIA Ownership Type
Column5     Age Bracket
Column6     Gender
Column7     Channel Type
Column8     Exclude Non Producers
Column9     Firm
Column10    Firm Type
Column11    License
Column12    Retail BD Type
Column13    Retail BD Primary Type
Column14    Years A Rep
```

Output Expected:

```
Snapshot Date,Quarter End,Year End,RIA Ownership Type,Age Bracket,Gender,Channel Type,Exclude Non Producers,Firm,Firm Type,License,Retail BD Type,Retail BD Primary Type,Years A Rep
1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,1
```

How to rename all columns in single script?
I want to use this to 500+ csv files and Source file columns are not in same order.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
df

   SourceColumns                  Rename
0        Column1           Snapshot Date
1        Column2             Quarter End
2        Column3                Year End
3        Column4      RIA Ownership Type
4        Column5             Age Bracket
5        Column6                  Gender
6        Column7            Channel Type
7        Column8   Exclude Non Producers
8        Column9                    Firm
9       Column10               Firm Type
10      Column11                 License
11      Column12          Retail BD Type
12      Column13  Retail BD Primary Type
13      Column14             Years A Rep

df2

   Column1  Column2  Column3  Column4  Column5  Column6  Column7  Column8  \
0        1        2        3        4        5        6        7        8   

   Column9  Column10  Column11  Column12  Column13  Column14  
0        9        10        11        12        13        14
```

---

Use `df.rename` on the columns with a column mapping:

```
df2 = df2.rename(columns=df.set_index('SourceColumns')['Rename'].to_dict())
df2


   Snapshot Date  Quarter End  Year End  RIA Ownership Type  Age Bracket  \
0              1            2         3                   4            5   

   Gender  Channel Type  Exclude Non Producers  Firm  Firm Type  License  \
0       6             7                      8     9         10       11   

   Retail BD Type  Retail BD Primary Type  Years A Rep  
0              12                      13           14
```

Comment: @faithon.gvr.py Welcome! Don't forget to vote and accept if it helped.

Answer (score 0):

In Pandas version 0.21.0 [`set_axis`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.set_axis.html#pandas-series-set-axis):

```
source_df.set_axis(columnNameDF['Rename'].values, axis=1, inplace=False)
```

Output:

```
   Snapshot Date  Quarter End  Year End  RIA Ownership Type  Age Bracket  \
0              1            2         3                   4            5   

   Gender  Channel Type  Exclude Non Producers  Firm  Firm Type  License  \
0       6             7                      8     9         10       11   

   Retail BD Type  Retail BD Primary Type  Years A Rep  
0              12                      13           14
```